Can I apply for a 6 month visit visa
I am 20 year old Nigerian who currently rounded up her university and is yet to have a graduation ceremony. The ceremony is set for November. I wish to apply for a uk visit visa. I was born in England but has never been since then. I wish to apply for this visa independently of my parents and siblings

You can, but 6 month visit may issue red flags, so you must have good reasons, and good funds and good intention to exit UK. As new graduate you may see the problem. Also consider your country: there are many abuse from there (people tend to forget that Nigeria is also the most populous country in Africa, nearly the double of the second one). -- I'm not sure how people could answer your question, but with a "yes" or "it depends" (possibly the question is too generic)

Are you asking am I eligible to apply? or if I apply will I get the visa? The answer to the first question is Yes, to the second it’s apply and find out.
